# Intercept Socket.io packets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

There is a videogame that uses canvas via socket.io

Using the Chrome developer tool I can see that binary packages are being transmitted containing information that I would like to read from an external medium.

Is it possible to intercept these packets in real time or decode them to be able to read them? Perhaps using JavaScript or another language.

I've been looking for topics related to it but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a web proxy to me? A good one is maybe Telerik Fiddler2 or OWASP ZAP to intercept the traffic before hitting your browser (need to configure proxy settings inside the browser to make this work)?